# Batch: read file names from file, search them, add found path to file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, find, cmd

I'm trying to write script which will read 1st values from csv file (i.e. 1st column from each row), contains filename.
Then search this file in some location, and add every found path to csv, as a new last column.
I have next script, which just tries to search files. 
But it doesn't work correctly. Seems like I have empty %reportname% in this row:

```
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %%N IN ('dir /b /A:-D /s %reportname%')
```

full script:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set currentdir=%CD%
set grspath=\Sources\ROL\Kesko\grs13\
set filename=sqrscripts.csv
set tmpfilename=scripts.new
SET reppath=""
SET reportname=""

IF NOT "%1"=="" grspath=%1

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8* delims=;" %%a in (%filename%) do (

    SET tempstr=%%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;%%e;%%f;%%g;
    SET reportname=%%a

    echo Serching !reportname! in %grspath% ...

    cd %grspath% 
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%N IN ('dir /b /A:-D /s %reportname%') DO (
        IF NOT "%reppath%"=="" (SET reppath=%reppath%,%%N) ELSE (SET reppath=%%N)
        )
    cd %currentdir%

    echo Found: %reppath%
)
```

Could you please look into this, maybe you can find something wrong?

My Input:

```
E:\tmp>(
SET tempstr=art.rep;1;2;3;4;5;6;7
 SET reportname=art.rep
 echo Serching !reportname! in e:\Sources\ ...
 cd e:\Sources\
 FOR /F "tokens=*" %N IN ('dir /b /A:-D /s ""') DO (IF NOT """" == "" (SET reppa
th="",%N )  ELSE (SET reppath=%N ) )
 cd E:\tmp
 echo Found: ""
)
```

and then may rows like:

```
E:\Sources\>(IF NOT """" == "" (SET reppath="",E:\Sources\somefolders\somefile.someext )  ELSE (SET reppath=E:\Sources\somefolders\somefile.someext ) )
Found: ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. % replaced to ! in the inner blocks:

```
    cd %grspath% 
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%N IN ('dir /b /A:-D /s !reportname!') DO (
        IF NOT !reppath!==!! (
                SET reppath=!reppath!;%%N
                echo !reppath! - new one !!!
                ) ELSE (
                SET reppath=%%N
                echo !reppath! - new one !!!
                )       
        )
    cd %currentdir%
    echo !reppath! - new one !!!!
    IF NOT !reppath!==!! SET tempstr=!tempstr!;!reppath!

    echo !tempstr!>>%tmpfilename%
```